# Deploy Python/Bash application on Aws

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I am new in the Cloud
and I have an python script that I call from a bash script with parameters. this app run on Linux and required some python modules as well. 
I would like to deploy this app on the AWS cloud and make it run on a given schedule.
What is the best way to deploy this app (AWS Lambda or EC2).
Thanks

Nono

Answer (score 2):

Cheapest way is AWS Lambda, but you'll have to get rid of the bash script and modify your Python script some.

Easiest way is EC2, because it's just a Linux server that you can login to and install whatever you want and setup your script on a cron job just like your local Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Using an EC2 instance gives you more flexibility to apply changes/modifications to our app and scripts. As an example; adding and updating libraries to the EC2 instance is easier than lambda as in lambda you need to add the required libraries to your local machine, create a new package and re-deploy your lambda function.

Cost wise as it is also mentioned in the previous answer, lambda would cost less, as you pay only when your scripts executes, but you can take advantage of free-tier EC2 instances for a limited time. And if your app does not need a lot hardware resources, general purpose EC2 instances with less processing power such as micro ($0.0104 per Hour) should does the work.

For EC2 instances pricing check 
[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/)